# remove slash , blackslash using FART

Tags: java, string, batch-file, cmd, fart

how can i remove/replace "/" from a text file ? am using FART for this , it's working okey for all the characters but for some reason it doesn't see the "/" character

```
Fart.exe --remove myFile.txt "/"
```

Comment: Try -c switch `C --c-style       Allow C-style extended characters (\xFF\0\t\n\r\\ etc.)
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, try with -C option

```
-C --c-style       Allow C-style extended characters (\xFF\0\t\n\r\\ etc.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Fart.exe --remove --c-style myFile.txt "\/"
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone trying to replace `/` with `\`:

```
fart.exe -C "your_file.txt" "\/" "\\\\"
```